# Unnecessary space on PHPmailer mail message body

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a form with an required radio input that is followed by an optional text input and a required textarea. 
When all form items are filled, the message body sent by mail is ok, but 
the problem is when only  item1 (radio input) and item3 are filled: 5 unnecessary blank lines are added between item1 and item3 in the mail message body. I did some tests and found out that the problem is in the way item1 variable is declared. How can I fix this issue?

html:

```
<div class="checker">
    <input class="check" type="radio" name="item1" id="item1" value="xxxx" data-validation-engine="validate[required]"><label>xxxx</label><div class="effec"></div>
</div>
<div class="checker zog">
    <input class="check" type="radio" name="item1" id="item1" value="yyyyy" data-validation-engine="validate[required]"><label>yyyyy</label><div class="effec"></div>
</div>

<input class="fullinput" type="text" id="item2" name="item2" value=""  >

<textarea id="item3" class="require_text" name="item3"  data-validation-engine="validate[required]"></textarea>
```

Here are the variables:

```
//item1
$item1 = isset($_POST['item1']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['item1']): "";

//item2
if (isset($_POST['item2']) && !empty($_POST['item2'])) {
        $item2 .= "\r\n";
        $item2 .= "■land"."\r\n" . $_POST['item2'];
}

//item3
$item3 = isset($_POST['item3']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['item3']): "";
```

Here is the message content:

```
■お問い合わせ区分
$item1
$item2

■お問い合わせ内容
$item3
```

Mail Message wrong result:

```
■Item1
xxxxx






■Item3
dsdsdsd
```

Comment: remove `$type .= "\r\n";` and try.

Comment: It has no effect, when item2 is not filled....

Comment: Show the HTML, especially the textarea.. sounds like your posting them newlines. [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the contents

Comment: show how you are displaying `$item1` `$item2` &so on

Comment: I have added my html

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, I checked the mail without item1, and there was no problem with text area display.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, I just found the problem, playng attention on your words, the item2 is generating extra space, even when is empty. How can I fix it?

Comment: As mentioned before use trim(), also check the javascript code is not adding it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, could you write a code using trim as an answer, as I cant write the right expression using php.

Comment: You could simply put the following at top of your page `$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);`